# SELinux - how do I call my custom interface?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, selinux, libselinux, linux-security-module

I wrote a new policy contains new type definition (.te) and interface method (.if):

.te file:

```
policy_module(dummy, 1.0.0)

type dummy_t;

files_type(dummy_t)
```

.if file:

```
## <summary>
##  Do Bla bla
## </summary>
## <param name="domain">
##  <summary>
##  Domain allowed to read files.
##  </summary>
## </param>

interface(`dummy_int',`
    gen_require(`
        type dummy_t;
      ')

    allow $1 dummy_t:file read;
')
```

Now I'm writing a new policy and want to call dummy_int macro:

.te file:

```
policy_module(callinterface, 1.0.0)

type callinterface_t;

dummy_int(callinterface_t)
```

But - Compiling this policy generates the following error:

```
[root@localhost callinterface]# make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile 
Compiling targeted callinterface module
callinterface.te:5:ERROR 'syntax error' at token 'dummy_int' on line 3329:

dummy_int(callinterface_t)
/usr/bin/checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
make: *** [/usr/share/selinux/devel/include/Makefile:157: tmp/callinterface.mod] Error 1
```

The 'dummy' policy is compiled and installed properly.

What am I doing wrong? how do I make the compiler know this macro?

I tried to wrap the macro implementation with ifndef statement as described here:
[fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/IndependentPolicy](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/IndependentPolicy#Using_custom_interfaces)

under *Backwards compatibility* section - no change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The interface file should be stored in /usr/share/selinux/mcs/include/* or /usr/share/selinux/devel/include/* (depending on the Linux distribution).

[creating-our-own-interface](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781783989669/1/ch01lvl1sec12/creating-our-own-interface)

When I copied the .if into this folder, the policy had compiled successfully.